# Count does not tally with total

Tags: counting

I code the following to count events.

```
Count[Table[RandomInteger[{1, 6}], {i, 10}], #] & /@ Range[6]//Total
```

By right, if I total, I expect 10. Sometimes it gives < 10, sometimes more than 10.

I want to generate a random number between 1 and 6 and wanted to how many time count each occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: `Table[RandomInteger[{1, 6}], {i, 10}]` is being evaluated six times, and is different in each instance. Use `Tally[]` or `Counts[]` instead.

Comment: Or `With[{table=Table[RandomInteger[{1, 6}], {i, 10}]}, Count[table, #] & /@ Range[6]//Total]`, though I'd really use `Counts`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because each time you `Count` (that is, for each element of `Range[6]`) you're creating a new array of `RandomInteger`s to `Count`. Rewriting your `Table` just as a `RandomInteger` list, consider

```
SeedRandom[1]
Count[RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 10], #] & /@ {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

By your reasoning, this should produce the same number six times -- however many threes there are in the `RandomInteger` array. But what it actually produces is

```
(* {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3} *)
```

because each time `Count[RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 10], #] &` evaluates, it's generating a new array.

Try a different approach, and create your random array first:

```
SeedRandom[1]
rand = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 10];

Count[rand, #] & /@ {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
Count[rand, #] & /@ Range[6] // Total

(* {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)

(* 10  *)
```

as expected.

As people have pointed out, `Map`ping `Count` over a `Range` looks like you might be trying to get the functionality of [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html), which counts up how many times a particular element appears in the list. So, on the previous example:

```
KeySort@Counts[rand]

(* <|1 -> 5, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 5 -> 2|> *)
```

and `Total` works just the same:

```
Total @ %

(* 10 *)
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.